# undefined local variable or method `byebug'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, byebug

I have the follwing error:

> NameError (undefined local variable or method `byebug'

Code is

```
def  test
  t = ""
  byebug
end
```

--

> RAILS_ENV=development gem list | grep bye
>
> byebug (3.5.1)

then I run :

> RAILS_ENV=development rails s

but it shows:

> NameError (undefined local variable or method `byebug'

Do you have any idea why?

Thanks!

Comment: Is it in your Gemfile?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

It seems you need to

[require 'byebug'](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug/issues/33#issuecomment-27342940)

I was in the same situation and require failed with 'cannot load such file' error but adding to the Gemfile worked.

Comment: Rails 5 development on windows like `LoadError:
  cannot load such file -- byebug` and I just want to throw my computer out the window. Sorry for hijacking your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you haven't installed the gems with `bundle install --without development` option.

If that is the case just run `bundle install --with development`

Answer (score 1):

Add byebug gem into development group

```
group :development, :test do
   # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
   gem 'byebug'

   # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
   gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0.0.beta4' 
end
```

Then run this command  **bundle install --with development**