# undefined local variable or method `byebug', already in Gemfile and required

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging, byebug

I have the same problem as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26391867/undefined-local-variable-or-method-byebug). I use `byebug` in this class:

```
class BasesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_available_bases, only: [:index]

  def index
  end

  private
  def set_available_bases
    byebug
    @bases = Base.all
  end

end
```

And I get

```
NameError (undefined local variable or method `byebug' for #<BasesController:0x5952e10>):
```

If I add `require 'byebug'` as proposed in the first answer, I get `cannot load such file -- byebug`. byebug is already, by default with Rails 5, in my Gemfile

```
group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platform: :mri
end
```

I have already run `gem install byebug`, `bundler install`. I have ruby 2.3.3p222, rails 5.0.1, running on Windows 10.

Any idea of how to solve this?

Comment: I am suspicious about the name of controller, why `Base`? does it work with other controllers?

Comment: @Md.FarhanMemon It's named after a model, but I have the same problem with other controllers as well.

Comment: Have you done all the sanity checks? Restarting spring `spring stop`, bundle update byebug etc?

Comment: The problem might be in Windows. Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41674136/byebug-fully-supports-windows-or-not.

Comment: @Niklas I'm new to ruby, what are those sanity checks?

Comment: @yzalavin Windows was it, thanks!